# C idioms for selectively assigning structure fields

Tags: c, structure, updates

Suppose we have a structure that represents the state of some object, and a function that sets the values in that struct.  Side effects of the assignment are important -- changing the state of the object affects hardware, for instance -- which is why the assignment is a function and not simply done inline with '='.

```
typedef struct foo_s {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} foo_t;

void foo_create (foo_id_t* id, ...);
void foo_set (foo_id_t id, foo_t* new_values);
```

After creation, perhaps clients want to change their foo a bit, so they fill in a foo_t struct and call foo_set.  The question is what elegant idioms are there in C for allowing a partial structure assignment, changing a specified subset of the fields and leaving the rest as they were before?

Ways I've thought of:

1) Read-modify-write:  Call get, change some fields, call set.  Requires the implementation of set to compare every field to detect actual changes.  Potential locking issues between the read and write.  Potential performance issues depending on the storage used for the foo_t.

2) Accessor functions: one set function per field would let you call just those functions you need.  Drawbacks include a tremendous proliferation of individual functions; locking issues for an entire transaction; and difficulties coordinating sequence if several fields must change together to make sense.

3)  Bitmap of fields:  Add a bitmap as a parameter to set, or embedded in the foo_t, to indicate which fields are valid.  Client code sets the appropriate bits, fills in corresponding fields, and calls set().  Drawbacks include manual maintenance for parallel bit definitions for each field; small bit of extra work for the client.  Locking and sequence can be handled by the set implementation.

4)  List of offsets:  Similar to (3), but passing a variable-length array of the offets into the foo_t of fields that were changed (offset_of() comes in handy).  Implementation of set() iterates down the list, comparing offsets against the structure to know which fields were changed.  Eliminates the manual duplication of (3), but requires the array to be passed (pointer and length).  Forces the client to declare or malloc() such an array, which is a bit clumsy.

5) Property list:  Rather than fields in a structure, the object could be represented as a list of names of object properties (that is, an enum).  Individual properties could be set with a function like foo_property_set (foo_id, foo_property, void* property_value, int property_len);  This style allows arbitrary access to individual fields and future expansion.  Disadvantages arise when the goal is to change multiple fields together -- transactional locking would be required; some actions might require several related properties to be changed together; and there's extra overhead in repeated function calls for many properties.

What coding patterns do you use to handle this problem?

Comment: You can do 3 and 4 with an opaque parameter like the `fd_set` parameter to `select()`.

Answer (score 0):

How about an accessor macro?

```
#define SETFOO(fooptr, member, value)  ((fooptr)->member = (value))
```

This is like approach 2), except you don't proliferate functions, you have just the
one macro.  Can't help you with the locking issues, you'll just have to provide functions
to lock and unlock before doing any changes.  As far as "coordinating sequence if several fields must change together to make sense", you can't change multiple fields atomically in
C anyway.  Even a whole structure assignment is basically a memcpy().

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that the most natural solution is not on your list: object orientation. I am not talking about C++ here, I am talking about using the paradigm of object orientation in C.

You can view your structure as a class, and you can define any number of methods that modify it in the ways you need. Just define one method for each high level operation you need, these methods are the only ones that directly modify your `struct foo_s`; all other code simply makes sequences of calls to these methods. You can even call your functions using a scheme like `foo_methodName()` to signal to which "class" they belong.

With that, you don't need to create any complex scheme to modify several fields at once.